# In solidity, struct has some mistaken?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

```
contract MyContract {
struct Posposal{
    uint posposalId;//防止复核数组变动时
    address voteSponsorAddr;//投票发起人

    bytes1 description_;//投票内容信息  0 转币  以后扩展
    uint userId;//投票给目标以太币地址所对应的id
    uint amount;//转多少代币
}
Posposal[] public curPosposals; //当前提议投票记录
uint public posposalNextId=0;// 标识投票建议递增  

function MyContract() {

}
uint public expId;
address public expTarget;
uint public expAmount;
function issuse(uint userId,address target_,uint amount_)  {
    //投票目标用户肯定是存在的
    expId=userId;
    expAmount=amount_;
    expTarget=target_;
    curPosposals.push(Posposal(posposalNextId,msg.sender,0x01,userId,amount_));//0 未投票 默认情况  1支持票 -1 反对
    posposalNextId++;
}}
```

Why the `curPosposals[0]` is wrong? But when I move `bytes1 description_;` to the end of struct `Posposal`, all are designed answer. Why?
Following :

invoke function and pass params:
[image]

the result:

[image]

`expId=2 (right);` and
`curPosposalId[0].userId` should be 2, `curPosposalId[0].amount` should be 20000, but they are wrong. Why?

Comment: How are you fetching curPosposals[0]?

Comment: I could fetching by the ethereum wallet(mist), the result before.When I type 0, the User id(0) and Amount(512) are wrong, but actually 1, 20000 are right。

Comment: It is working fine on solidity browser.